# MAMPとSymfonyで、作成したアプリを表示したいがroutes.yamlに入力したURLを打ち込んでもNot Foundになってしまう。

Tags: php, macos, mamp, symfony

いま、Symfonyを勉強しています。

MAMPを使って、作成したページをブラウザで表示させたいのですが、routes.yamlで登録したURLを入力しても表示されませんでした。

以下のことを行いました。

---

1. コントローラとtwigを以下のコマンドで作成

   ```
    php bin/console make:controller
   ```
2. route.yamlを編集

   ```
    home_page:
       path: /home_page
       controller: App\Controller\HomeController::index
   ```
3. 以下のコマンドを実行

   ```
    composer require symfony/apache-pack
   ```
4. `"localhost:8888/mysite/home_page"` をブラウザで入力

---

これらを試しても
"Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.　
と表示されてしまいました。

作成したファイルは MAMP/htdoc.にあります。

しかし、 "`localhost:8888`"や "`localhost:8888/mysite`" を入力すると各ディレクトリに作成した index.html をブラウザで表示することができます。

ですが "`localhost:8888/mysite/home_page`", を入力しても "`php bin/console make:controller`". で作成したTiwgをひらくことができません。

問題がわからなくてこまっています。

Answer (score 0):

http://localhost:8888/mysite/public/index.php/home_page
でいけないですかね？
こちらでMAMPを使ってSymfonyを動かしてみたら、これで動きました。
（publicフォルダ以下のindex.phpはCodeigniterではフロントコントローラーと呼ぶみたいです。）

virtualhostを設定して
例えば、http://localhost:5005/home_pageにアクセスしたら
http://localhost:8888/mysite/public/index.php/home_page
にアクセスされるようにしておくとスマートかもしれません。